# How to compare the oxidizing power of perhalate ions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, reactivity

In my book the oxidizing power in descending order of the following is given as: $\ce{BrO4-} > \ce{IO4-} > \ce{ClO4-}$

My doubt is regarding their order of oxidizing tendency.

I thought that chlorine has the highest electronegativity, so can help oxygen stabilize the $-1$ charge the best and be least reducing (electron donor) and most oxidizing.  Looks like that’s not the case.

Another possibility was that iodine was the largest ion there, it’s far bigger than oxygen, so maybe it produced some instability which made the negative charge unstable, or in other words it became more reducing. In that case it should be least oxidizing (which is also not the case unfortunately).

I couldn't just make out whats so special about $\ce{BrO4-}$ that makes it the most oxidizing ion

Although this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49596) gives a bit of a good hint but doesn't answer my question completely.

Comment: I would love it if you can find a duplicate for me because anyways i am not getting an answer here @orthocresol

Comment: Sorry Shubham, @orthocresol is right -- his answer to the stability question also answers the oxidizing power question. Bromine is the least stable of the three in the high $+7$ oxidation state... so what is it likely to do to become more stable? Oxidize something!

Comment: The question does approach the matter from a different angle, though, and so it may be useful to have it open.

Comment: @brian okay i take ur point that it may have some common points regarding bro4-. But what about the order of the other 2 ions? The question doesnt only ask about bro4-

Comment: Shubham Good point. I recommend editing your question to add a link to @orthocresol's answer, and then describing why it doesn't fully answer your question.

Comment: @orthocresol This is *not* a dupe, because it is not immediately apparant from the *question* that these will go in the same direction. For a dupe to be a dupe we need the essentially same answers **and the essentially identical question.** This one approaches the problem from a different angle.

Comment: @orthocresol oh i am sorry... Actually i read the duplicate question and its answer partially in the beginning. Later i found it somewhat useful. Thanks

Comment: Between perchlorate and periodate I think it is a bit subtle. There are possibly effects arising from differences in the form of the oxyanion in solution (ClO4- vs H5IO6 according to Housecroft) but a possible crude approach would be to rationalise it based on the weak I-O (or I=O) bonds. Not 100% sure so I will refrain from writing an answer... Perbromate is most oxidising due to the d-block contraction as described in my other answer.

Comment: I thought you guys at stack exchange know everything.  This is the first time i am not getting an answer